# Ability to filter flagged posts by tags

Tags: feature-request, flags

There are way too many posts that have been flagged in StackOverflow, or at least that has been my perception for the past few days.

I believe it would be useful to add tags for filtering these posts. There are posts that one could come back to later, because it is not within one's domain of expertise, but reading such posts often takes time. Filtering on tags would make it easier to sift through flags. It exists for the page where new user posts (and first and late answers) are reviewed, so I thought it should be present in the Flagged posts page as well.

[image: RFE for filtering on flags]

Comment: Also being able to filter by answer/question would help much. Answer flags can usually be easily handled by everyone, whereas question flags need to be within one's field of expertise.

Comment: Almost two years later. Nothing changed. When things do or don't change I usually find out that the SE powers have very good reasons for it. But this is one I really don't understand. I wouldn't mind to help out every now and then, but this random list makes my head spin and it drains all goodwill in minutes. It is _discouraging_, like being faced with a huge task you are to carry out without a plan.