# Sorting of flagged questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, sorting

The https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged page shows all sorts of questions that have been flagged by less-than-privileged users for more privileged users to confirm.

This page sucks, mainly because:

> This list is in random order.

I have no experience with C# or smarty or winforms or gwt or iobservable or excel-vba or almost any of the tags shown on this page.  Thus, I am largely unqualified to decide whether or not this question is truly "very low quality", "not an answer", "not constructive", or "too localized".  I, of course, can do my best to wade through the ones marked "duplicate" or "vandalism", etc, but the random ordering of this list makes this *extremely* tedious.

I would much rather see this listed sorted by my active tags.  The stuff at the top should be the stuff that most closely matches the tags in which I participate, followed by everything else.  That way I can open the flagged page and immediately be able to make decisions on "yes this is crap" or "no that's not crap" or whatever.  My time is valuable, and having to hunt through this randomly ordered list means I'm never going to spend it on this page.

Comment: I've asked for [something similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95451/ability-to-filter-flagged-posts-by-tags) today. Maybe the feature requests can be merged.

Comment: @Vineet yep, similar idea.  I like it! :)